# Hibernate criteria to return a List that contains values from a column

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a user table, how do I create a `Criteria` that returns me a `List<String>` of all the values in the name column in the user table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Criteria.setProjection`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyUserObject.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("name"));

List<String> list = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use projections like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class)
                       .setProjection(Projections.property("name"));
List<String> names = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = this.currentSession().createCriteria(ABC.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("name")));

List<String> names = criteria.list();
```

**Projections.distinct** will help you get unique records